# Custom nullptr_t class

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, c++03

I tried to write a `nullptr_t` class based on [the official proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf) to be used in C++03 only. The only differences with the proposal are that we can compare two `nullptr_t` instances and that it is convertible to `bool` via an overload to `void*` to avoid unwanted behaviour such as `int a = nullptr;` for example. Here is the class:

```
const class nullptr_t
{
    public:

        // Return 0 for any class pointer
        template<typename T>
        operator T*() const
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Return 0 for any member pointer
        template<typename T, typename U>
        operator T U::*() const
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Used for bool conversion
        operator void*() const
        {
            return 0;
        }

        // Comparisons with nullptr
        bool operator==(const nullptr_t&) const
        {
            return true;
        }
        bool operator!=(const nullptr_t&) const
        {
            return false;
        }

    private:

        // Not allowed to get the address
        void operator&() const;

} nullptr = {};
```

I would like to know if there is any actual flaw in this completed implementation or if there is a difference in the behaviour compared to the C++11 type `std::nullptr_t` besides the namespace that I can't see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the moment, your implementation allows

```
auto& p = nullptr;
```

This is forbidden in C++11 as `nullptr` is an rvalue.  You also do not allow the following:

```
auto p = nullptr;
auto pp = &p;
```

While C++11 does allow it.  You are also missing overloads for comparison operators.

A simple workaround would be to remove the `operator&` overload and add a macro:

```
#define nullptr (nullptr_t())
```

Also, I'd generally use `struct X { ... } const x;` instead of `const struct X { ... } x;`.

Answer (score 7):

Another thing I forgot at the time is that the standard specifies that `sizeof(nullptr)` shall be equal to `sizeof(void*)`.

> 3.9.1 - Fundamental types
>
> 3.9.1.10 A value of type `std::nullptr_t` is a null pointer constant (4.10). Such values participate in the pointer and the pointer to member conversions (4.10, 4.11). `sizeof(std::nullptr_t)` shall be equal to `sizeof(void*)`.

So technically speaking, I should have added padding to my `class`:

```
class nullptr_t
{
    // To ensure the size
    // Should be correctly aligned
    void* padding;
    // ...
} const nullptr;
```

Comment: Could you provide full implementation including C++11 improvements to nullptr ... I would be grateful.

Comment: That `sizeof` requirement is a nuisance.  I see two issues with adding that `padding`:
1) I'm not sure that copying around an uninitialized `void *` is well-defined.  I considered replacing it with `unsigned char padding[sizeof(void *)]`, but that didn't solve the next issue, nor would adding empty copy operators.
2) Including a `private` non-`static` member variable breaks POD-ness, at least before C++11.  I don't see a good way around this.